# railsでurlのみを生成するヘルパー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`link_to`だとaタグごと作られちゃいますが、urlだけを作るヘルパーってないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for)を使うといいと思います。

```ruby
# パスのみ
url_for(@foo)
# => /foos/1

# 絶対URL
url_for([@foo, only_path: false])
# => http://localhost:3000/foos/1
```

Answer (score 3):

Groupというモデルがあったとするとこんな感じでURLが取得できます。

```
group = Group.find 8

groups_url
# => "http://www.example.com/groups"

group_url(group)
# => "http://www.example.com/groups/8"

polymorphic_url :groups
# => "http://www.example.com/groups"

polymorphic_url(group)
# => "http://www.example.com/groups/8"
```

"url"の部分を"path"に変えるとpathだけが取得できます。

```
groups_path
# => "/groups"
```

Host名（ドメイン名）は以下の設定で変更します。

- [ActionMailerの場合](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views)
- [ActionControllerの場合](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails)